# Excel - Subtract time from

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am creating a basic Excel Formula for working on rosters, but I am finding a challenge in minus the time they take on their lunch break.

This varies from 1 hour, 45 minutes or 30 minutes.

So far I can minus the times to get the hours they worked, but I just cannot seem to find the right formula to minus **D4** from the total.

At present I have `=text(C3-B3, "h:mm")` though whatever I try to include the D4 fails. Any help definitely appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

works with:

```
=TEXT(C3-B3-D4,"h:mm")
```

Set format C3 and B3 to time '[$-409]h:mm:ss AM/PM;@'
and cell D4 to 'h:mm'

[image]

Comment: Your answer contains valid information, however it doesn't answer the question. Please give advice which solves the actual problem instead of writing general statements and suggesting workaround (you suggest to use `45` instead of `0:45`). Or explain why there is no good answer for the question and why your workaround is the correct way instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've edit my answer, so now it hopefully fits to the question.

Comment: Or, alternatively, leave out the `TEXT(…)` function, just do `=C3-B3-D3`, and format the cell to display the way you want.  For example, since `D3` seems to be formatted as an amount-of-time rather than a time-of-day, you could click on `D3`, click on “Format Painter”, and click on `E3`.